# PayPal Direct Payout PHP Code

Tags: php, paypal

I am an admin with business type paypal account and I paid to receive a paypal email id.

The problem is that there is no transaction id or transaction details given from paypal. It is not possible to change the receiver paypal account setting. In this case the Payer account is only one but the receiver is multiple. You pay to only a single user in a single transaction, so there is no need to use adaptive or change payment.

Please provide PHP code for this, with help to pay with direct payout and get a response.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$sender_batch_id = mt_rand(100000000000000,999999999999999);
$sender_item_id = mt_rand(100000000000000,999999999999999);

$access_token = 'A21AAGpxXlEt3iIG7fKiriFDdLwIW_JJvpOa9IwVb8XXJbeVjL9MkHvmYWbWkHgVReeiuEQaYZTbi6xSWbXGMlLaabJPwkdYg';  //Dummy


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true");    //DUMMY

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"sender_batch_header\":{\"sender_batch_id\":\"$sender_batch_id\",\"email_subject\":\"You have a payout!\",\"recipient_type\":\"EMAIL\"},\"items\":[{\"recipient_type\":\"EMAIL\",\"amount\":{\"value\":\"1.0\",\"currency\":\"USD\"},\"note\":\"Thanks for your patronage!\",\"sender_item_id\":\"$sender_item_id\",\"receiver\":\"sanjay@rudrainnovatives.com\" }]}");  //DUMMY


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer $access_token";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
pr(json_decode($result));
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

This code help to pay with Paypal Single Payout.